# Bigger font-size for code in some list items on documentation

Tags: bug, documentation, design, code-formatting

When I look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/462/metaprogramming/8524/manual-distinction-of-types-when-given-any-type-t#t=201608251327329551285, I see the following:

[image]

In the second list (the one that is not numbered), the font size of the code blocks is bigger than in the first list. If I am not wrong, the correct size if the first one (`13px`), while the second one seems to inherit the default font size for text on documentation (`14px`).

Note that in the preview, the output is correct (both code blocks have a font size of `13px`).

I am using Firefox ESR 38.5.0.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the issue is that that second piece of code isn't wrapped in a `<p>` element.

The CSS responsible for setting the (proper) size on the first bit is:

```
.example p code, .remarks p code {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

However, there's no `<p>` in the tree between `li.example` and `<code>`, for the unordered list. For some reason, the first (ordered) list *does* add paragraph element in each `li`, while the second (unordered) list doesn't:

> [image]